# Información proyecto flask

Tags: python, flask

estoy con un proyecto de python en flask y estoy atascado. Voy a intentar resumir mi problema para simplificar. Tengo un input con un check

```
<input onclick="/preguntas-selec/{{ preguntas.id }}" class="check" type="checkbox" value="">
               - Estándar
```

y quiero que cuando le clicke, se ejecute esta función de mi main

```
@app.route("/preguntas-selec/<id>")
def selec(id):
    pregunta_seleccionada = db.session.query(Preguntas).filter_by(id=id).first()
    tipo = pregunta_seleccionada.tipo
    result = db.session.query(Preguntas).filter(Preguntas.tipo == tipo).all()
    db.session.commit()
    db.session.close()
    return redirect(url_for("paginacomenzar"))
```

Tengo una tabla en un .db que contiene preguntas, las cuales tienen id, y tipo. Mi objetivo es referirme en el check a un tipo de pregunta, para luego guardar todas las de ese tipo en una variable. Creo que la función del main está bien, pero el check sé que no, porque no sé como indicarle que al clickar me estoy refiriendo a una pregunta cuyo parametro tipo sea el 1 por ejemplo.

Disculpen si me expliqué mal, pero estoy totalmente bloqueado y no salgo de este problema.

Comment: Tendrías que hacer una petición con javascript usando `fetch`

Comment: No entiendo de javascript así que nada, con esa info no puedo hacer nada.